# Removing credits from mkdocs material

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

In `mkdocs` with `material` theme, how I can remove credits at the bottom.

> Made with Material for MkDocs

[image]
Is there any settings in `mkdocs.yml` for this?

Gone through documentation(https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/changing-the-colors/), couldn't find any direct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.
Workaround is to have below in `mkdocs.yml`

```
...
nav:
  - Home:
    - Room under home: index.md
    - Another room under home: home.md
  - About: about.md
extra_javascript:
    - 'javascripts/removeCredits.js'
...
```

Create a file `docs/javascripts/removeCredits.js` as below:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    removeCredits();
});

function removeCredits(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.md-copyright')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].remove();
    document.querySelectorAll('.md-copyright')[0].childNodes[1].remove();
}
```

**Change the indices of DOM elements as per your situation. If you are using another `copyright` from `mkdocs.yml` file, then `DOM` will change.

Answer (score 5):

You know - the footer displays a ***Made with Material for MkDocs*** notice to denote how the site was generated. The notice can be removed with the following option via `mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
extra:
  generator: false
```

Please read [this](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/setting-up-the-footer/#generator-notice) before removing the generator notice (**Note:** I'm not connected to this project.):

> The subtitle Made with Material for MkDocs hint in the footer is one of the reasons why this project is so popular, as it tells the user how the site is generated, helping new users to discover this project. Before removing please consider that you're enjoying the benefits of [@squidfunk's](https://github.com/squidfunk) work for free, as this project is Open Source and has a permissive license. Thousands of hours went into this project, most of them without any financial return.

> Thus, if you remove this notice, please consider sponsoring the project. Thank you